# Linking tesseract libs

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I'm having trouble using tesseract.
I've downloaded the source code and compiled successfully.
Then I created a project in VC++ and I'm trying to do the first steps.

I created a simple program and included

```
#include <baseapi.h>
```

On project properties -> Linker -> Additional Dependencies i`ve put all the libs that tesseract generated

> ccmain.lib ccstruct.lib ccutil.lib classify.lib cube.lib cutil.lib dict.lib image.lib libtesseract_tessopt.lib libtesseract_training.lib neural_networks.lib textord.lib viewer.lib wordrec.lib

I also set the path of libs on Additional Libraries Directories. It seems to recognize the libs. But the problem is that i`m getting the following error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'baseapi.h': No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me? I`m just starting and it is difficult.

As an update, I've set the paths and included the files on my solution. But I'm getting different errors on ccutil.h.

**fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory   **

Due to this code

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

On your project you need to add the path to the tesseract headers in "Additional Include Directories".